# Why can't I access `this` within an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

This code below should work as expected, and log `"meow"`, [here an example](https://jsbin.com/zovamuyano/edit?html,js,console).

```
function Cat () {
  this.animalNoise = 'meow' 
}

Cat.prototype.sound = () => {
  console.log(this.animalNoise)
}

let cat = new Cat()
cat.sound()
```

It doesn't work, this error appears `TypeError: Cannot read property 'animalNoise' of undefined` and when you convert the arrow function to an actual `function` declaration it works. It seems like with the arrow function, I no longer have access to `this`. What's going on here?

To be clear, **the above code does not work** where the following does, and I'm very curious why.

```
function Cat () {
  this.animalNoise = 'meow' 
}

Cat.prototype.sound = function() {
  console.log(this.animalNoise)
}

let cat = new Cat()
cat.sound()
```

Comment: An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds the this value** -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: There have been multiple questions about this already. Please use the search.

Comment: In general though, I'm curious how/where people learn about arrow function *without* also learning about how `this` behaves in arrow functions. That difference is such an integral part of arrow functions that it seems impossible to me to not know about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Arrow functions perform *lexical binding*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and uses the surrounding scope as the scope of `this`. For example, imagine (for some weird reason) you define `Cat` inside of a `Dog` constructor.

```
function Dog() {
  // do dog like things
  function Cat() { ... }
  Cat.prototype.sound = () => {
    // this == instance of Dog!
  };
}
```

So whatever the *surrounding* scope is becomes the scope of an arrow function.

Comment: Every function is lexically scoped though. It's just `this` (and `arguments`) that is special in arrow functions.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point. Edited answer to be more accurate.