# javascript: value of 'this' is different between debugger and actual result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects

In a client-side only app, I'm loading two js files with script tags, one after another, and getting errors as appear in the comments below:

obj.js

```
'use strict';

let obj = {};

obj.func1 = () => {
  return 'stuff';
}

obj.func2 = (arr) => {
  debugger; // in devtools, value of 'this' is obj, as expected
  console.log(this); // clicking 'next' button in devtools,
                     // the object that is actually being printed to
                     // console is the window object!!!
                     // javascript, wtf?!?!
  debugger;

  let myStuff = this.func1(); // fails because window has no 'func1' property

  ...
  ...
}

window.obj = obj;
```

script.js

```
'use strict';

obj.func2()
// Uncaught TypeError: this.func1 is not a function
```

Why in the world does it happen? Why there's a difference in 'this' value between devtools debugger and actual result in the browser?

Edit:

See in the screentshot below how, when I'm executing `console.log(this)` myself in the console while being paused by the `debugger` break point, 'this' *is* Object(), and one step next (believe me that it's exactly one step next), window object is being printed to console.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of this line: `debugger; // in devtools, value of 'this' is obj, as expected`. Why my devtool shows `this` is the `window` object?

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 IDK, I was able to repro in chrome beta (50) on linux mint and chrome canary (51) on OS X. What browser version/OS are you testing on?

Comment: @JaredSmith I've attached a screenshot in my answer. I'm on Win7_x64 with Chrome 49.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 per minusFour's comment, you're actually showing the problem in your screenshot :P

Comment: This seems a duplicate of [What does “this” refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982/1529630). The debugger thing seems an unrelated browser bug.

Comment: @Oriol disagree somewhat. Although the OP clearly did not understand what `this` is supposed to mean in arrow functions, it seems the *inconsistency* is what prompted the question. So I would say the browser bug is integral rather than unrelated. Just me $0.02

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196) . Also yes, there seems to be a bug in Chrome where it doesn't show the correct value for `this` in arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` in an arrow function is implicitly bound at the point of creation. Whatever `this` is in the context wherein the function is created will be the value of `this` when the function is invoked.

```
obj.func2 = (arr) => {
  // ...
};
```

is basically equivalent to

```
obj.func2 = function(arr) {
  // ...
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: so arrow functions aren't equivalent to 'regular' functions?

Comment: @Kludge in this respect, no. They're like functions returned from `.bind()`.

Comment: So why the values don't match between devtools and actual result?

Comment: @Kludge which values don't match? What "devtools" are you talking about?

Comment: See the 'debugger' break point. At that very moment, devtools shows that the value of 'this' *is* obj, like I expected

Comment: Then the browser debugger is broken. What browser are you using?

Comment: methinks should be `bind(obj)` instead `bind(this)`

Comment: Are you using a transpiler, or native browser arrow functions? Transpilers don't usually rename variables for debugging well.

Comment: @Grundy it's OK that you think that but the language disagrees :)

Comment: @loganfsmyth, no transpilers

Comment: @Pointy, Doh! Your right! confuse with method _inside_ class

Comment: @Pointy, Is there a way to use a more elegant, es6ish minimal way of writing functions, without the arrow function's default binding as you just explained?

Comment: Able to reproduce bug, Chrome 50 on linux mint.

Comment: The debugger isn't broken. The `this` you're viewing in the debugger is created ATM you're inspecting it, which _is_ `obj`.

Comment: @Creynders that doesn't make sense. At that moment in the execution flow there's no implicit `this` binding in the arrow function, which means it goes up the scope chain.

Comment: @Creynders I can't agree that this isn't a broken behavior. It's totally weird, sorry :P

Comment: @Kludge No. if the `this` binding is important, then use `function`. Arrow functions are useful for things where you want the outer `this` like event handlers and returning functions from functions. They weren't meant as a drop-in replacement for `function`.

Comment: btw, @Pointy, thanks for your help, meanwhile I'm using `obj` instead of `this`, to avoid the bind change. I'm leaving the question not answered in order to see if I can get clearer answer regarding the bad status devtools reports, IMHO