# this keyword behaves differenty in arrow functions and normal functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following 2 statements:

Without arrow function-

```
var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .on("click", (d) => {
            console.log(d);
            zoomIn(d,this);
    });
```

With arrow function-

```
var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .on("click", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            zoomIn(d,this);
    });
```

The first one gives a `window` object in `this` while the second one gives the object returned by `attr()`. I read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6). Is there a way to bind the object rather than the `window` object **using arrow functions.**

Comment: If you want dynamic `this`, use `function`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, arrow functions cannot be binded, as they simply do not define this in scope, just use this from outer scope.

Depending on what value this has in outer scope, that value will be used inside function. In your case it seems to be window object.

This does not differ greatly from using any other variable from outer scope.