# how can $(this) not be the element that triggered the event in a jquery click handler?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple click handler

```
<h1 id="test">
```

```
$('#test').click( ev => {
   var $test = $(this);
   console.log($test.text());
})
```

but it does not work, `$(this)` is not the emitter element. If I inspect `this` I see a "window" (?) (??) (??!)

also, if I change my code to

```
var $test = $(ev.toElement);
```

it works perfectly.

how can this be? what is in my code that prevents jquery to correctly pass the element in `this` ?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: In this fiddle I just made up, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/x1pf3vuo/

Comment: [What does “this” refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: @chalarangelo No it doesn't. It shows the entire page's text (equivalent to `$(document).text()`), not the clicked element's text.

Comment: @Juhana, you are right, I just hadn't put any more text, so I thought it had something to do with the printing on the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions do not bind `this`, `arguments` etc. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and lexically binds the `this` value (does not bind its own
>   `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`).

Comment: OMG !  that's it !!

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions do have a "lexical this". That means that the value of `this` inside of your function is the same as outside of it. And since the value of `this` in the global scope is `window` you also get that value in your event handler.

You have to use a normal function like this if you want your code to work:

```
$('#test').click( function(){
 var $test = $(this);
 console.log($test.text());
})
```

You can't set the value of `this` of an arrow function in any way.

```
var f1 = () => this
var f2 = function(){return this}
f1.call("hello") // --> window
f2.call("hello") // --> "hello"
```

`this` is always lexical for arrow functions

```
function foo(){
  return () => this
}

foo.call(true).call(false) // --> true
```

For more information on arrow functions have a look at the [mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Yury Tarabanko has already answered your question: Arrow functions do not bind `this`. This can come in handy if you're writing something like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<button>Click me to say hello!</button>

// JS:

class Foo{
  constructor( $button ){
    this.$button = $button;

    $button.click(() => {
      this.sayHello();
    });
  }

  sayHello() {
    alert('Hi');
  }
}

new Foo( $('button') );
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhkkLfty/

Play with this code for a while. Just change `() => {}` into `function() {}` and console.log `this`.

Edit: For more information, check out one of the following articles:

- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/
- http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html