# Access an injected dependency inside a function that we pass to another object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda, dependency-injection, aurelia

Apologies for not really knowing how to phrase this question. The crux is that on redirect back to the app, the redirect handler needs to have access to the injected `UserManager`.

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { UserManager } from "oidc-client";
import { OpenIdConnectRouting } from "./open-id-connect-routing"; 

@autoinject
export class OpenIdConnect {

    constructor(
        private routerConfigurationService: OpenIdConnectRouting,
        public UserManager: UserManager) { }

    public Configure(routerConfiguration: RouterConfiguration) {

        this.routerConfigurationService.ConfigureRouter(
            routerConfiguration,
            this.PostLogoutRedirectHandler);
    }

    public PostLogoutRedirectHandler = (): Promise<any> => {
        return this.UserManager.signoutRedirectCallback(null);
    }
}
```

The above code passes the `PostLogoutRedirectHandler` to a routing service, so that, when the user returns from the authorization server, the handler will fire.

The above code works, but the handler is lamda only to capture the current object in `this`. When the handler is instead a `function`, `this` is not what we expect it to be and we lack access to the injected `UserManager` object.

Why does the above code work with a lambda but not with a function? Is using a lambda a reasonable approach? If not, is there a way to do this with a function?

Edits:

This is the function/method version of the above handler.

```
public PostLogoutRedirectHandler(): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.Debug("PostLogoutRedirectHandler");
    return this.UserManager.signoutRedirectCallback(null);
}
```

It throws the following error:

> Cannot read property 'UserManager' of undefined

Of course, using the lambda `arrow function` works. Is this `arrow function` approach a reasonable pattern or an anti-pattern? What are its costs?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem, but could you not just `bind` the function?

Comment: What does it mean to `bind` the function?

Comment: It will bind the `this` context to your `OpenIdConnect` instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: I think this post will clear things up for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the problem: `Cannot read property 'UserManager' of undefined`.

Comment: @robbmj So it sounds like the answer is that using a lambda is fine, and that binding the function is the way to do the same thing with a function. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if it is right, but I suspect he means binding the function like this:
    `this.routerConfigurationService.ConfigureRouter(
            routerConfiguration,
            this.PostLogoutRedirectHandler.bind(this));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.bind(this)` to pass `this` object for outer execution function like callbacks or promises:

```
function(){
  //code what will be execute out from current object
}.bind(this)
```