# 'this' is undefined in Javascript arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, dom-events, arrow-functions

In the callback function of Javascript event, `this` is clicked element:

```
  document.querySelector('#my-element').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this);  // <div id="my-element">
  });
```

But, when I use ES6 arrow function, `this` becomes `undefined`:

```
  document.querySelector('#my-element').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(this);  // undefined
  });
```

Can someone, please, explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Arrow functions have a lexical `this` binding. There are many other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6?rq=1) around this.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions, when called, don't cause `this` to be bound. It'll have whatever value it had in the enclosing lexical scope. In your case, that means `this` in the enclosing scope is `undefined`.