# How does .this work in ES6 arrow functions & how is it different from ES5 .this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to see some examples/ clarification on how to use .this in ES6 following the arrow function syntax and how its different from ES5 .this binding.

Comment: [What does “this” refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6) – The difference from `.bind(this)` is that you can't remove it and have an unbound arrow function.

Comment: See also [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward:

In ES6 you have arrow functions which are "anonymous" in that they have no proper context. Therefore, `this` refers to the parent context.

In ES5, the equivalent is a function which DOES contain its own context. The way to use `this` correctly (assuming you want the parent's context) is to bind it like so:

```
function something() {//}

// invoke
something().bind(this);
```

Comment: Do you mean `something.call(this)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following functions in es5:

```
        // Scope Problem in es5 :

    var defaultPower = "Laser Vision";

    function superHero() {
      this.defaultPower = "Ice Ray";
      setTimeout(function grantPowers() {
        console.log("Super " + this.defaultPower);
      })
    }

    var IceMan = new superHero();
    // Console logs erroneous "Super Laser Vision"

    // Scope Fix in es5 by using self or _self or that var

    var defaultPower = "Laser Vision";

    function superHero() {
      var self = this;
      self.defaultPower = "Ice Ray";
      setTimeout(function grantPowers() {
        console.log("Super " + self.defaultPower);
      })
    }

    var IceMan = new superHero();
    // Console logs correct "Super Ice Ray"
```

and in es6:

```
      // And with arrow functions:

  var defaultPower = "Laser Vision";

  function superHero() {
    this.defaultPower = "Ice Ray";
    setTimeout(() =>  {
      console.log("Super " + this.defaultPower);
    });
  }

  var IceMan = new superHero();
  // Console logs correct "Super Ice Ray"
```