# Why arrow function is behaving weirdly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Consider the following code:

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.showName = function() { console.log(name, this.name);}
}

var foo = new Person('foo');

var bar = new Person('bar');

foo.showName = bar.showName;

foo.showName(); // prints "bar foo"
```

It is expected as this still binds "foo".

Now with arrow functions:

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.showName = () => console.log(name, this.name);
}

var foo = new Person('foo');

var bar = new Person('bar');

foo.showName = bar.showName;

foo.showName(); // prints "bar bar"
```

I know that 'this' doesn't bind to arrow functions. But here context of "foo" has changed in showName(). This itself removes the one use-case of "bind" function. What is the reason behind it.

Comment: For a good explanation, have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an arrow function, `this` is resolved lexically, basically like any other variable, e.g. like `name`. It doesn't matter how the function is called, its `this` value will be determined when the function is *created*.

Therefore, `this` inside `bar.showName` will always refer to the instance created by `new Person('bar')`.

---

See also [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982/218196) and [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) .

Comment: I don't know. I felt like it was worth talking about this specific example. But I don't don't have a strong opinion about it.

Comment: @mplungjan I read that question before but I think this was some specific example. Even you can assign variable to arrow function and this will always point to original object only. This was something new and so I think duplicate is not appropriate.

Comment: Reopened and linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6