# How do I call a function from within a nested function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to call the function `func2` from within sample function of function `func1`. Can someone suggest a way to achieve that?.

```
class A
{
   public func1()
   {
     let sample = function()
                  {
                    //call func2... but how?
                  }
   }
   public func2()
   {

   }
 }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `this.func2()`?

Comment: @Benjamin: Depends on what `this` refers to inside `sample` (i.e. how `sample` is called).

Comment: nop....scope of this is only in func1...not within sample(nested) function.

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Thank a lot Felix for the link. :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword with the `arrow` function notation like this:

```
class A
{
   public func1()
   {
      let sample = () => 
      {
         this.func2();
      }
   }
   public func2()
   {

   }
 }
```

The trick is using the `arrow` function, because the `arrow` function changes the definition of `this` to be the instance of the `class` instead of the current scope.You can read more [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Comment: That depends on what `this` refers to inside `sample`.

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that by using an `arrow` function that will use the correct scope.

Comment: Awesome.......that works.......could you please explain me how it works?

Comment: Its an anonymous function i believe.....but then how is it different from named function......would appreciate if you provide me any link that explains it.  Thank you once again.

Comment: @user3107338: Because arrow functions don't have their own `this`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982/218196 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196 .

Comment: I updated the answer to show some explanation and a link to a more detailed article