# JQuery: Using () => {} and function() syntax, latter works

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background**

I'm just giving jQuery a go and for an hour, I could not hide an element using `$([selector]).hide([milliseconds])`, which in my sample code, is called when I click the element, in this case the anchor tag `<a>`. But I got it working in the end, but I don't understand why so. The only change I needed to make using the `function` keyword, instead, so this:

**Note**: Examples used `this` not "a", see edits

```
event => {
 $(this).hide(2000);
}
```

into this

```
function(event){
 $(this).hide(2000);
}
```

**Question**

*Why does using function work and using an 'arrow' function doesn't? Is there a difference between the two?*

My source code, for testing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
    a.test{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>   
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script>
        // $(document).ready(function () {
        //     // $("a").click(event => {
        //     //     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
        //     //     //prevents the opening of the link (what are the default events of other events types?)
        //     //     event.preventDefault();
        //     //     //Special Effects - http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/
        //     // });

        // });
        $("a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $( this ).hide(2000);
        });
        $("a").addClass("test");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you use `this` within your arrow function, such as `event => $(this).hide(2000)`? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6

Comment: `function(event) => {
 $("a").hide(2000);
}` that looks wrong

Comment: Oops, yeah I meant it without the => in that part. Thanks

Comment: @le_m Yes I did

Comment: @ManWithAComputor Then you should change your code samples, because `event => $('a').hide(2000)` works, but not when using `this`.

Comment: @le_m Yeah, sorry. I was using `this` in both cases. but I've implicitly changed it to the "a" in my head. I need to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow function does not create a new scope tethered to `this`.  So, to get around this, just use a normal function (like bellow).  Alternatively, you could do `$(event.currentTarget).hide(2000);` inside your arrow function.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
    a.test{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>   
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script>
        $("a").click(function(event) {$(this).hide(2000)});
        $("a").addClass("test");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Arrow function does not create a new scope tethered to this` - so does `this` refer to the current event? I thought that this referred the element selected.

Comment: I understand it now, arrow functions do not get their create their own `this` value, instead this gets it value inherited from the scope that the function it is in. In my case, this refers to the `Window` object when using arrow functions.