# Callback with arrow function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

Let's say there are two functions.

```
function foo(callback) {
...
}

function bar() {
...
}
```

What's the difference when I call `foo(bar)` and `foo(() => bar())` by assuming bar requires no parameters?

I recently former one occurs error regarding `this` context, while second one works just fine. I know arrow function binds `this` context into the function, I have no idea what's the difference.

FYI, here is the code with issue.

```
socket.disconnect(socket.connect); // line 1

socket.disconnect(() => socket.connect()); // line 2

socket.disconnect(function() { socket.connect(); }); // line 3
```

I just found that the problem might not be related to the context. It might be something with apply or bind. Because line2 and line 3 works fine, while only line 1 shows error.

Comment: Have you researched the subject of `this`? There is a lot of info on SO which you can find with a simple search...

Comment: _"I know arrow function binds this context"_, no it doesn't bind any context, `this` will be whatever it was in the outer scope.

Comment: "Arrow functions are anonymous and change the way this binds in functions." I read it in a doc.

Comment: Yes in that they don't bind anything in the first place: _"An arrow function does not have its own `this`; the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used"_ [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I just found it's not fat arrow issue... But I am still curious what's the difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you are describing has nothing to do with arrow functions.

The value of `this` depends on how a function is **called**. When a function is a property of an object and called as `foo.bar()`, then `this` inside `foo.bar` will refer to `foo`.

So in your last two examples, `this` will refer to `socket` instead `socket.connect`.

In your first example `this` will refer to another value because the function won't be executed as method of `socket`. But `socket.connect` probably expected to have `this` referred to `socket`.

---

Simplified example:

```js
function foo(callback) {
  callback();
}

var socket = {
  connect() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this);
  },
};

foo(socket.connect);                  // undefined
foo(() => socket.connect());          // socket object
foo(function() { socket.connect()});  // socket object
```