# React: TypeError: existingChildren.set is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying to call setState in the success function of axios and I am getting below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: existingChildren.set is not a function
    at mapRemainingChildren (react-dom.development.js:6824)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:7320)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7672)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7788)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7771)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:8024)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8257)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10244)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10308)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:540)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:579)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:436)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10386)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11000)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:10952)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:10861)
    at scheduleWorkImpl (react-dom.development.js:10744)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:10706)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:6204)
    at App../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState 
 (react.development.js:226)
    at App.js:86
    at <anonymous>
```

This is the code from where the error is getting generated:

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios
     .get('/api/fetchMapData')
     .then(
       function(response) {
         this.setState({ mapData: response.data });
       }.bind(this)
     )
     .catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
 }
```

I assume it has something to do with the way I am rendering the component which causes the issue.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <BreadCrumb
          data={this.state.breadCrumb}
          setCountryView={this.setCountryView.bind(this)}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() =>
              <Home
                setMapView={this.setMapView.bind(this)}
                mapData={this.state.mapData}
              />}
          />
          <Route path="/country/:country" component={Country} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

Any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: change `then(function(response) {` to `then(response => {` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6

Comment: still I get the same error.. well arrow function is just a syntactic sugar right?

Comment: no arrow functions change the way `this` gets bound

Comment: also sorry, just noticed your `.bind(this)`