# callback returning true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering what I am missing here I have a code that checks if the image is transparent based on canvas.

```js
function Trasparent(url, npc, clb) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var maxlength = Math.sqrt(img.width * img.height) * 5 + 300;
        if (canvas.toDataURL().length < maxlength) {
            clb(false, npc);
        } else {
            clb(true, npc);
        }
    };
}
```

When I'm doing it this way:

```js
        function Trasparent(url, npc, clb) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = url;
            img.onload = () => {
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                var maxlength = Math.sqrt(img.width * img.height) * 5 + 300;
                if (canvas.toDataURL().length < maxlength) {
                    clb(false, npc);
                } else {
                    clb(true, npc);
                }
            };
        }

        function callback(success, npc) {
            if (success) {
               console.log("Not trasparent");
            } else {
               console.log("Trasparent");
            }
        }
        
        
        Trasparent(npc.icon, npc, callback);
```

It works just fine, but when I'm trying to make this function above like this:

```js
function Trasparent(url, npc) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var maxlength = Math.sqrt(img.width * img.height) * 5 + 300;
        if (canvas.toDataURL().length < maxlength) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
}


if(Transparent(npc.icon, npc)){
  console.log("Not transparent");
} else {
  console.log("Trasparent");
}
```

It doesn't work...

Even tho in this example which i wrote it works fine:

```js
function check(a, b) {
 var result = a + b;
 if (result <= 10) {
  return (false);
 } else {
  return (true);
 }
}


function test() {
 if (check(5, 4)) {
  console.log(">10");
 } else {
  console.log("<10")
 }
}
test();
```

What i am missing?

Comment: spelling mistake in function name Transparent (instead of Trasparent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The return-statements are not belonging to the function `Transparent`!

You are creating a different function here which returns true or false when it is called, but it is not executed right away and it's return-value is not returned in your function `Transparent`.
What you have is essentially this snippet:

```
function Trasparent(url, npc) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      // function body totally unrelated to the Transparent-function 
      // and not executed and not returning anything right now
    };
    return undefined;
}
```

(these are not actually the same since fat arrow functions capture `this`, see [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6))

Your solution with the callback is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

your code is async. you cant return true or false. you need to return a callback thats why your if doesn't work

```js
function Trasparent(url, npc,cb) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var maxlength = Math.sqrt(img.width * img.height) * 5 + 300;
        if (canvas.toDataURL().length < maxlength) {
            cb(false);
        } else {
            cb(true);
        }
    };
}


Transparent(npc.icon, npc,function(result){
    if(result)
      console.log("Not transparent");
    } else {
      console.log("Trasparent");
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: spelling mistake in the function called and declared

Comment: I missed the spelling cuz i was copying it from my source and just renamed it for exapmle here. So it is just my fail, any way even tho spelling is correct it doesnt't work