# addEventListener click is not working and not effecting the elements

Tags: javascript, events, click, addeventlistener

This is my code:

```js
let navi = document.createElement("nav");

let navItems = {
 home:"/",
 my_profile:"/me"
};

let btnClasses = ["bttn-minimal","bttn-md","bttn-primary"];

const redirector = ()=>{
 window.history.pushState(null,null,this.getAttribute("data-to"));
};


for(let i in navItems){
 let navItem = document.createElement("button");
 for(let c=0;c<btnClasses.length;c++){
  navItem.classList.add(btnClasses[c]);
 }
 navItem.innerHTML = i.toUpperCase().replace(/_/g," ");
 navItem.setAttribute("data-to",navItems[i]);
 navItem.classList.add("navi-item");
 navItem.addEventListener("click",redirector);
 navi.appendChild(navItem);
}

document.getElementById("navi").appendChild(navi);
```

The `navItem.addEventListener("click",redirector);` is not working. The script tag is at the end of the body tag. I also tried using

```js
navItem.onclick = redirector;
```

and it's the same. Not only it's not working i can't see the event listener in the chrome dev tools. Please help.

I tried using a regular function but it's same. Two reasons:

1. I'm using babel so what the browser gets is a regular function.
2. I'm not even getting an error, the browser simply ignores it.

Also, i'm calling that code from a Browserify local require.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: Babel actually changes `this` semantics for arrow functions. Have you tried `console.log(this);` in that function?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as the event handler.

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` object; instead, they use the `this` of the scope around them.

If you need `this` in the event handler, use a regular function instead of an arrow function.

```
const redirector = function () {
    window.history.pushState(null,null,this.getAttribute("data-to"));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener works just fine:

```js
let navi = document.createElement("nav");

let navItems = {
 home:"/",
 my_profile:"/me"
};

let btnClasses = ["bttn-minimal","bttn-md","bttn-primary"];

const redirector = ()=>{
  alert('click!');
 //window.history.pushState(null,null,this.getAttribute("data-to"));
};


for(let i in navItems){
 let navItem = document.createElement("button");
 for(let c=0;c<btnClasses.length;c++){
  navItem.classList.add(btnClasses[c]);
 }
 navItem.innerHTML = i.toUpperCase().replace(/_/g," ");
 navItem.setAttribute("data-to",navItems[i]);
 navItem.classList.add("navi-item");
 navItem.addEventListener("click",redirector);
 navi.appendChild(navItem);
}

document.getElementById("navi").appendChild(navi);
```

```html
<div id="navi"></div>
```

But as Xufox and PeterMader mentioned `this` did not refer to the clicked button...

You might workaround this way:

```
const redirector = e => {
  window.history.pushState(null, null, e.target.getAttribute("data-to"));
};
```

Comment: @Xufox, the question is `addEventListener click is not working`, not the `callback` does not work