# Get value of data attribute inside anchor

Tags: jquery, html

I need to write some events where application contains series of anchor link with different data in data-attribute. i have wire an event (click may be) which can pull data-attribute value data-product-d and data-product-name for clicked anchor

My HTML looks like

```
<div class="product-availibility">
  <p>Available from Etsy starting at <strong>$26</strong>
  </p>
  <a class="button lnk_tracking" href="https://www.etsy.com/listing/269790426/name-necklace-gold-name-necklace-gold" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="Non-Amazon" data-product-name="Name Necklace">See Now</a>
</div>
```

There are almost 10 divs with same class. On click on anchor, need to pull data-attribute

Comment: Ok, so where are you stuck?  Are you just looking for the `.data()` function in jQuery?

Comment: $('.product-availibility a').on('click', () => {
            
            alert(this.tagName);
            alert($(this).closest('button lnk_tracking').data('data-product-id'));  }); gives undefined

Comment: @jvm: Why are you using `closest` there? You are already hooking the click event on the `a` tag itself. `$(this).data('data-product-id')` should work.

Comment: $(this).data('data-product-id') comes undefined

Comment: @jvm: `$('.product-availibility a').on('click', function () {console.log($(this).data('product-id'));});`  (1) Not sure what you were trying to do with `.closest()` there.  (2) Don't include the prefix `'data-'` in the data keys, just use the key itself.

Comment: console.log($(this).data('product-id')); also comes as undefined

Comment: @jvm, please update your question with a complete example.

Comment: I think () => is causing issue. I replaced with function() and it works

Comment: @jvm: Yes, the binding of `this` is different when using the arrow syntax.

Comment: See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on the question above...

```
$('.product-availibility a').on('click', () => {
  alert(this.tagName);
  alert($(this).closest('button lnk_tracking').data('data-product-id'));
});
```

1. You don't need (or want) to use `.closest()` here.  The `<a>` is the element you're looking for, and this event already targets that.
2. Even if you were using `.closest()`, the selector you're passing to it is looking for the structure `<button><lnk_tracking /></button>`, which of course doesn't exist.  (It looks like you meant to use class selectors, which are prefixed with a `.` like in your first selector.)
3. When using the `.data()` function, don't include the `'-data'` prefix for the key.  Just use the key itself.

It sounds like you're looking for this:

```
$('.product-availibility a').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('product-id'));
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/taLmbv1L/).

Note that I also changed the `() =>` structure to `function ()`.  I'm not sure if this was breaking solely in jsFiddle, or if this is necessary.  To be honest, I haven't actually used the `() =>` syntax before.  But the function syntax is working.

Comment: The reason for the `()=>` vs `function()` is that in the arrow function, `this` is bound to the scope of the outer function. So, it's probably `window` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.product-availibility a').on('click', function() {
            console.log($(this).data('product-id'));
    });
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.