# For loop not working in an object's method

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I started to work on my memory mini game, but stopped right after start :( `For` loop is not working for me.
My code:

```
const game = {
   ...
   shuffledCards: [],

   startGame: () => {
    ...
     // clear variables
     this.shuffledCards = [];

     for (let i = 0; i < this.cardsCount; i++) {
        this.shuffledCards.push(Math.floor(i/2));
     }
   }
}
```

I want to generate an array which looks like this`[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2...]`, but that `for` loop returns an empty array. Do you know why? When I try to change variables from `this` to normal ones and paste the code into browser, it works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions do not inherit `this`. You need to rewrite your code as

```
const game = {
   ...
   startGame() {
     ...
     this....
   }
   ...
}
```