# Jquery selector .each() selecting document

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to get the height of my elements that contains class `category`. I wan't to use `.each()` function but it seems to return me the entire document. There's my code :

```
$('.category').each((index) => {
    console.log($(this).height());
});
```

This return me :

`828` (the document height)..

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using an Arrow Function, which [binds the `this` value of the enclosing context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372106/1814486).

Use a regular `Function`.

```
$('.category').each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).height());
});
```

I know they look cute and all that but they are **not** perfect replacements for regular Functions.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked. So arrow function doesn't bind this ?

Comment: @JeremyM. That's right