# this is undefined on event listeners

Tags: javascript

I wonder why if i declare a function outside the listener function, `this` will be undefined but if i delcare the function inside the listener function `this` will be defined..

working:

```
someClass.each(function(i) {
  someClass.eq(i).on('click', (e) => {
    var targetClass = this.classList[0],
    console.log(targetClass);
  });
}); // this will be defined as the clicked class
```

not working:

```
someClass.each(function(i) {
  someClass.eq(i).on('click', buttonClick)
}); 
buttonClick = (e) => {
    var targetClass = this.classList[0],
    console.log(targetClass);
}); // this will be undefined
```

Comment: you need to understand how `this` works inside an arrow function

Comment: `this` works differently (or not at all) for arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6

Comment: `someClass.each` looks like jquerey - so this in the callback (I think) is the current item in `someClass` - i.e. if you were to `someClass(function(i, x) {` ... this would be `x` - which is why your first code works and the second does not

Comment: note, your first code would also fail if you wrote it like `someClass.each(i => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use non-arrow functions for methods that will be called using the object.method() syntax. Those are the functions that will receive a meaningful this value from their caller.

Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context. So you can't use arrow functions in those scenarios.

[Source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) (Especially the "What’s this?" section)

[More sources](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

Answer (score 0):

The scope changes when you enter that anonymous closure and in your second function 'this' points to the Object outside the buttonClick function. You can do the following to make your code work,

```
buttonClick = (e) => { // I'm assuming e = event object
    var targetClass = e.currentTarget.classList[0], 
    console.log(targetClass); 
});
```