# ES6 Arrow Function Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi guys I am a bit confused about the arrow function i read the arrow function documentation on mozila developers and I found out that the arrow functions cannot be used as constructors and will throw an error when used with new. but in this example I didn't get any errors it returns an empty object however I passed the parameters that I want to construct the object with.

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
let ConstructObjectArrow = (name, age, city)=>{
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.city = city;
}

let armin = new ConstructObjectArrow("Armin", 32, 'London');
console.log(armin);
```

the output is: ConstructObjectArrow {} and it has a proto not undefined as the documentation said.

Comment: I get `TypeError: ConstructObjectArrow is not a constructor`. In what environment are you testing?

Comment: @Sirko I am using an online editor here's the link https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: From the page you linked to the explanation to your question , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: *the output is: ConstructObjectArrow {} and it has a proto not undefined as the documentation said.* - no, it's not. If you're running this code with Babel, it obviously won't work as intended because an arrow is transpiled to regular function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an arrow function for a constructor and it does not make sense to do so.

By definition, an arrow function takes its `this` value from the lexical context.  Therefore, it will not have a `this` value from the new object, therefore it does not work as a constructor.

Because of this, the interpreter doesn't even let you try and generates a TypeError because you aren't passing an appropriate type of constructor function to `new`.

Remember that arrow functions are not just a syntactical shortcut, they cause a difference in behavior with the value of `this` and that difference is only appropriate in some circumstances.

You may want to read this article which explains further: [When not to use arrow functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/).

Internal to the Javascript implementation, a constructor must be a certain type of Function object which has various internal methods such as `[[Construct]]` and an arrow function does not have these internal properties.  Thus, when you attempt to call `new` on it, the interpreter discovers you are not passing the right type of function to `new` and thus it creates a run-time error.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElNasser - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.