# How to fix ‘Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined’ error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I'm creating a class to handle event in socket.io, and I can't call this.io.emit in this class.

```
-- Socket file
class Socket {
    constructor(io) {
        this.io = io;
    }
    run() {
        this.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            console.log('new client has connect', socket.id);
            this.io.emit('new-client', socket.id);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Socket;



typeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (C:\Users\truon\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectNodeJS\socket.js:8:12)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Namespace.emit C:\Users\truon\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectNodeJS\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:181:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Comment: use arrow functions. `this.io.on('connection', socket => { })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the callback function, `this` is not equal to the `Socket` instance.

You need to use `.bind` or use arrow functions instead.

```
class Socket {
    constructor(io) {
        this.io = io;
    }
    run() {
        this.io.on('connection', socket => {
            console.log('new client has connect', socket.id);
            this.io.emit('new-client', socket.id);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Socket;
```

Otherwise `this` is referencing the current Namespace object. If you don't want to use arrow functions, you can just do:

`this.emit('new-client', socket.id)`

```
run() {
    this.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
         console.log('new client has connect', socket.id);
         // this is referencing the Namespace
         this.emit('new-client', socket.id);
    });
}
```

You can read the following questions for more information regarding arrow functions & `this`.

- [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)