# After authentication from the firebase i want to store Name, Email in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, axios, state

I am developing Full stack Application IN Reactjs and Firebase I authenticatied successfully using signInWithPopup method after that I want store the credendials into local state.

I used this.setState in ComponentDidMount but getting an error. I even used axios but failed.

```
state = {

    } 

componentWillMount() {
       auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                var displayName = user.displayName;
                console.log(displayName);
                var email = user.email;
                console.log(email);
                var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
                console.log(emailVerified);
                var photoURL = user.photoURL;
                var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
                var uid = user.uid;
                var providerData = user.providerData;

                this.setState({
                    displayName:this.displayName
                })
               } else {
                window.location = "/signin";
            }
        })
    }
```

TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Firstly, you should show your whole code. Also, you shouldn't do this in `willMount`, it should be in `didMount`. Thirdly, if you use `function` you're not going to have access to the `this` of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {` (arrow functions). The `this` used inside arrow functions and normal functions are different.

Also do not use `componentWillMount` instead use `componentDidMount` for the firebase authentication. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372106/5893921) SO answer.