# Multiple forEach statements on this.prop causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array stored as a prop:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.letters = [];
}
```

Inside a `componentDidMount` method, I put this prop in a `forEach` loop that has a `setTimeout` in it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            letter.classList.add('stroke');
        }, index * 125);
    });
}
```

This works as expected, adding a class to each element inside the prop array.

Then I tried adding a second `forEach` loop after this one. This looks a little confusing, but it's basically the same as the first `forEach` loop, but it's wrapped inside a `setTimeout` so that it starts 1 second later:

```
    this.letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            letter.classList.add('stroke');
        }, index * 125);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        this.letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                letter.classList.add('fill');
            }, index * 125);
        });
    }, 1000);
```

With these two `forEach` loops on `this.letters` back to back, I get this error on the `this.letters.forEach...` line of the second loop:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

I tried setting `this.letters` as another variable inside `componentDidMount`, and used that variable instead of `this.letters`:

```
    const letters = this.letters;

    letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            letter.classList.add('stroke');
        }, index * 125);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                letter.classList.add('fill');
            }, index * 125);
        });
    }, 1000);
```

This works, but I'm not sure I understand why `this.letters` doesn't work?

I also tried replacing just one of the loops with the `letters` variable instead of `this.letters` -- the first loop works fine with `this.letters`, but the second loop doesn't work with `this.letters` no matter what.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => {
        this.letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                letter.classList.add('fill');
            }, index * 125);
        });
    }, 1000);` Use a fat arrow function to access `this` of parent scope.

Comment: Damn -- that's it. I've read something about fat arrow functions and how they work well with `this`, but hadn't fully grasped it. I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Not a duplicate, but see [What does “this” refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982/1541563) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const letters = this.letters;

    letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            letter.classList.add('stroke');
        }, index * 125);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                letter.classList.add('fill');
            }, index * 125);
        });
    }, 1000);
```

The issue is with the arrow (react uses es6 arrows as a way of binding this to functions).

`setTimeout(function() {` -> `setTimeout(() => {`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding