# I get Cannot GET /[object%20Object] on button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and learning click events. But the issue I faced is that one button click I get "Cannot GET /[object%20Object]". Here is the code I am using:

```
class Engine extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let types = ["Diesel", "Gazoline"];
    return (
      <div>
        <Car type={types} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Car extends React.Component {
  open() {
    console.log("You have clicked");
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <button onClick={open}>Remove all</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

ReactDOM.render(<Engine />, box);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this.open`, since it doesn't know exactly what you're referring to by `open` :

```
<button onClick={this.open}>Remove all</button>
```

If you were to have named the function, say, `foo` instead of `open`, then it wouldn’t have worked at all.

The reason why you're seeing the functionality is because it is using the default `open` command [built into](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) JavaScript, which opens a new page. Under the hood, clicking the button is calling `open(e)` where `e` is the button event. So it's trying to open a new page, but instead of it receiving a URL, it's receiving an `object`, and thus you're seeing the error you received.

Instead, you want to use the `open` that is defined in the class. In order to do that, you need to use `this.open`.

In addition, if you want to pass something to the function as an argument, you'll need to change it a bit.

You can change `open` to:

```
open = (myparam) => {
    console.log("You have clicked");
    console.log(myparam);
}
```

In order to [bind `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372106/3813411). Then you can do something like:

```
<button onClick={_ => this.open("foo")}>Remove all</button>
```

Comment: please can you explain why to use "this"

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the open function to component and also call it with 'this'.
Or you can make the arrow function.

```
<button onClick={this.open.bind(this)}
```

or

```
open = () => { ... }
<button onClick={this.open}
```