# What does 'this' refer to inside arrow functions that are defined inside IIFEs that are defined inside a method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

What I understand is that arrow functions don't rebind `this`, so why does it refer to different objects depending on how it's invoked?

```js
const foo = {
  speak() {
    (() => {
      console.log(this);
    })();
  }
};

foo.speak(); // Logs foo

const speak = foo.speak;

speak(); // Logs the global object
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: From mdn. An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; So, in the first case you use the scope of the object because it has its own scope, the second time `const speak` is defined in the global window. Which means calling `speak()` will use the lexical scope of the global window.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: ``this`` always looks at the object before it. Because it is not called the second time, the object before ``. `` is global

Comment: The arrow function is defined in the scope of the `speak` method, that's where it gets its `this` value from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow function is being defined and executed only when and each time `speak` is called.  The first time you call it is as a method on `foo`, therefore `this` is bound to `foo`.  The second time you call it, `this` is the window.  Compare to this version:

```
const foo = {
  speak: () => {
      console.log(this);
  }
};

foo.speak(); 

const speak = foo.speak;

speak();
```

Where the `speak` function *is* the arrow function and therefore the `this` is bound immediately to the `window` object for both calls.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions preserve the lexical value of `this`. What this means is, the value of `this` depends on how the arrow function is defined and not on how the arrow function is invoked.

The inconsistent behavior you see here is because the inner arrow function is being "defined" every time the function `speak` is being invoked. At that point of definition, the arrow function captures the current value of `this` which is different for `foo.speak()` and `speak()`.

As a side note, this seems like JavaScript trivia. I wouldn't expect a "real" codebase to have this kind of snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is, when you assign the function to the const variable it loses it scoping.

When you call `foo.speak()`, the speak function is **running** in the context of foo, whereas when you run `speak()` after assigning the foo.speak function to the const variable, the function is **running** in the context of the global (window) object.

MDN states:

> the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this