# Why do ES6's Proxy doesn't work when used inside a method of class?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

The logic doesn't work when used inside method of a class but works out side if I use it in functional style.

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    toStringProperty() {
        const handler = {
            apply: function (target, thisArg, args){
                if (thisArg === Function.prototype.toString) {
                    return 'function toString() { [native code] }'
                }

                if (thisArg === this.object) {
                    return "Hooked String"
                }

                return target.apply(thisArg, args)
            }
        }

        Function.prototype.toString = new Proxy(Function.prototype.toString, handler)
    }
}

let hook = new Hook(HTMLAudioElement);

hook.toStringProperty();

// Interesting enough this when called (I use Devtools) logs Proxy Object itself but only happen if I use a Class
console.log(Function.prototype.toString)

console.log(HTMLAudioElement.toString())
```

What should I do to make it works inside a class?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you need to create the proxy after the class is created.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nothing. Just experimenting ES6 Proxy with a class.

Comment: @luekbaja If you see code, you can see that I create the proxy after class initialization,

Comment: I don't understand the question. *What* doesn't work?

Comment: @VLAZ Proxification of course. Please run the code, and you will see that it logs the original value of HTMLAudioElement.toString() instead the one I want to return ("Hooked String")

Comment: OK, then this is what confused me. There is nothing wrong with the proxy - all calls *do* go through it. However, `this.object` is not what you think it is.

Comment: this.object refer to the object (It's a name) variable of the class. It's created by the constructor. The value of this.object  should be HTMLAudioElement

Comment: @VLAZ I'm 100% sure the word "object" is not reserved by JS. What's reserved is "Object"

Comment: [As you should know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) the value of `this` is not static and is determined at call time.

Comment: @VLAZ What should I do in this case to refer this variable then?

Comment: @VLAZ Ok, I found that I can refer it outside then refer it through different name. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is not with the proxy - all calls already go through it. The issue is the age old specifics of [how the `this` keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). In short, it's determined *at call time*, so `this.object` will have a different meaning depending on when and how the function is called. In this case, the value of `this` is "lost" [not unlike how you lose it in a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

If you need to refer to something concretely, you have a few choices

### Lexically bind `this` using an arrow function `() => {}`

An arrow function [uses the `this` value of the enclosing context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6) *at creation time*, so it doesn't vary at call time:

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    toStringProperty() {
        const handler = {
            apply: (target, thisArg, args) => { //<--- arrow function
                if (thisArg === Function.prototype.toString) {
                    return 'function toString() { [native code] }'
                }

                if (thisArg === this.object) {
                    return "Hooked String"
                }

                return target.apply(thisArg, args)
            }
        }

        Function.prototype.toString = new Proxy(Function.prototype.toString, handler)
    }
}

let hook = new Hook(HTMLAudioElement);

hook.toStringProperty();

// Interesting enough this when called (I use Devtools) logs Proxy Object itself but only happen if I use a Class
console.log(Function.prototype.toString)

console.log(HTMLAudioElement.toString())
```

### Manually bind `this` using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

This is basically redundant with arrow functions, but still an option:

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    toStringProperty() {
        const handler = {
            apply: function (target, thisArg, args){
                if (thisArg === Function.prototype.toString) {
                    return 'function toString() { [native code] }'
                }

                if (thisArg === this.object) {
                    return "Hooked String"
                }

                return target.apply(thisArg, args)
            }.bind(this) //<--- bind `this` from creation time
        }

        Function.prototype.toString = new Proxy(Function.prototype.toString, handler)
    }
}

let hook = new Hook(HTMLAudioElement);

hook.toStringProperty();

// Interesting enough this when called (I use Devtools) logs Proxy Object itself but only happen if I use a Class
console.log(Function.prototype.toString)

console.log(HTMLAudioElement.toString())
```

### Capture the value in a variable

This avoids the usage of `this` by capturing the value of `this.object` at creation time with `const obj = this.object` and just using `obj` later which will always have the same value:

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    toStringProperty() {
        const obj = this.object; //<--- capture 
        const handler = {
            apply: function (target, thisArg, args){
                if (thisArg === Function.prototype.toString) {
                    return 'function toString() { [native code] }'
                }

                if (thisArg === obj) { //<--- use
                    return "Hooked String"
                }

                return target.apply(thisArg, args)
            }
        }

        Function.prototype.toString = new Proxy(Function.prototype.toString, handler)
    }
}

let hook = new Hook(HTMLAudioElement);

hook.toStringProperty();

// Interesting enough this when called (I use Devtools) logs Proxy Object itself but only happen if I use a Class
console.log(Function.prototype.toString)

console.log(HTMLAudioElement.toString())
```