# Accessing a getter from a parameterized getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

**tl;dr**

How to access other getters from a parameterized getter?
Normally, you can use `this.myGetter`; but a parameterized getter is implemented as an arrow function, wherein `this` is undefined.
What's the preferred way to handle this case in Pinia?

---

I'd like to create a parameterized getter (`multiSum`) in my Pinia store, which accesses another getter (`sum`).

Getters can be accessed via `this`, but that won't work from within an arrow function which is used to implemented a parameterized getter: `multiSum` crashes because `this` is `undefined` in the context of the nested arrow function.

```js
getters: {
  sum: (state) => state.a + state.b,
  multiSum: (state) => (count) => this.sum * count // crash: this is undefined
}
```

In Vuex, parameterized getters can access other getters via a parameter instead of `this`, which also works in arrow functions. But afaik this API does not existing in Pinia.

I can work around this by capturing the store instance:

```js
multiSum(state) {
  const store = this
  return (count) => store.sum * count
}
```

This works, but is pretty verbose. Is there a better (more framework-compliant) way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` can be `undefined` inside arrow function because it's not interchangeable with regular function and gets a context from parent scope.

The usage of `this` and `state` is explained in details in [the documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#accessing-other-getters). Either `this` or `state` can be used, but `this` has better Typescript and thus IDE support.

In the first snippet, `state` is already available in function scope, there is no need to access `this`:

```
multiSum: (state) => (count) => state.sum * count
```

In the second snippet, `const store = this` isn't needed because a store is already `this`.

```
multiSum() {
  return (count) => this.sum * count
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was talking about the API you linked: in the docs it says "Access any other getter via this"; but this does not work with parameterized getters (https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#passing-arguments-to-getters) which are implemented as arrow functions. In the second snippet, `this.sum` fails because `this` inside the arrow function is undefined. Vuex provides a solution for this, by passing the `getters` object as optional argument to getters. (Will update my question.)

Comment: It seems that you have problems with the fundamentals of JS here. multiSum from snippet 2 is regular function that has `this` context. Arrow higher order function doesn't have its own `this` and gets the nearest context, which is multiSum's. `const store = this` is redundant in the OP.

Comment: You are right in that the 2nd example wasn't correct. If should read instead: `const store = this ; return (count) => store.sum * count` -- I can't use `this.sum` inside the arrow function, that's why I have to capture the outer `this` in a variable. But once again: I know why this doesn't work; I'm not asking for help with JS arrow functions, but rather for a solution in Pinia.

Comment: "I can't use this.sum inside the arrow function" - you can, if `this` is correct context. `const store = this; return (count) => store.sum * count` and `return (count) => this.sum * count` are absolutely the same when used inside `multiSum() {` regular (non-arrow) function.

Comment: They are not the same. In the one case I bind `this` in a variable outside the arrow function's scope, and can access it this way. Directly accessing `this` inside the arrow function does not work though

Comment: "Directly accessing this inside the arrow function does not work though" - can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? This isn't how arrow functions work, that's why I mentioned the problems with JS , the use of old recipe `var self= this` with arrows always indicates that there are some things about them that need to be studied. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6 . The reason why it didn't work in the OP as `multiSum: (state) => (count) => this.sum * count` is because both functions are arrows.

Comment: Aaah now I finally get what you mean. The reason why the 2nd example works is not because I captured `this` outside the arrow function, but rather because the arrow function is inside a non-arrow function. So I guess this is indeed the solution, plain and simple: just don't write the parameterized getter with 2 arrow functions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: How with this method you can access other getters inside getter?

Comment: @rendom Use regular function instead of an arrow and access the whole store as `this`, this is noted in the answer.