# Anonymous function: 'this' inside doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say I have this code, with normal function:

```js
let a = {
  parent: "roger",
  child: "bear",

  printName: function() {
    console.log(`${this.parent} ${this.child}`)
  }
}

b = {
  parent: "float",
  child: "bear",
}

a.printName.call(b)
```

The output is as expected:

> float bear

However, the same code with anonymous function doesn't work:

```js
let a = {
  parent: "roger",
  child: "bear",

  printName: () => {
    console.log(`${this.parent} ${this.child}`)
  }
}

b = {
  parent: "float",
  child: "bear",
}

a.printName.call(b)
```

This results in:

> undefined undefined

Even passing 'this' to anonymous doesn't seem to work:

```js
let a = {
    parent: "roger",
    child: "bear",

    printName: (this) => {
        console.log(`${this.parent} ${this.child}`)
    }
}
```

This results in a syntax error: Unexpected token this

Questions:

- Please explain why is this happening?
- How to get it to work?

Comment: It's already working. Use the first version.

Comment: "*How to get it to work?*" you ***cannot*** unless you change your code a lot. Yet, there doesn't seem to be a reason to really do that. Further reading: [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982) | [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710) | [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875) | [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202)

Comment: As clarification -> `function() {}` is an anonymous function,  and `() => {}` is an arrow function.  Could explain why you couldn't find the answer.. :_