# Javascript - why is this referring to global window if I pass an arrow function as callback vs defined same func inside the callback handler?

Tags: javascript, this

Why is the value of this in first example: this: myObject and document/window in the second example? If this is defined/evaluated when the function is called, then I dont understand it.

```
myObject = {
  myMethod: function () {
    helperObject.doSomethingAsync('superCool', () => {
      console.log(this); // this === myObject
    });
  },
};
```

```
const reusabledCallback = () => {
  console.log(this); // this === window or global object
};

myObject = {
  myMethod: function () {
    helperObject.doSomethingAsync('superCool', reusabledCallback);
  },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: also: [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions) and [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

- `this` in an arrow function is the same `this` as the one in the outer scope where the function is defined.
- `this` in a function declared with the keyword `function` is the object on which the function is being called.
- `this` in the global scope is the `window` object (or the relevant global object)

In your first code, the arrow function containing `this` is defined inside a `function`, so `this` is whatever called that `function` (`myObject` in your case).

In your second code, the arrow function containing `this` is defined in the global scope, so `this` is the global object (`window`).

Comment: But isnt this evaluated when the function containing it is run? Then even if reusabledCallback is defined in the global scope, when its run, it is also then defined inside a function which is invoked by myObject so shouldnt that be the same?

Comment: @juliascoding No, `this` in an arrow function is the `this` at the place where the arrow function is defined, not where it's executed.

Comment: ahh okay thank you! and this inside a function with function keyword is on the contrary is where its executed, right?!

Comment: Not really where it is executed, but *how* it is executed. If the function is called as `myObject.myMethod();`, then `this` inside the method will be `myObject`. If you do instead `const objectMethod = myObject.myMethod; objectMethod();`, then `this` inside the method will be `window`.