# Called on an object instance, instance method defined on the prototype returns undefined when referencing instance properties with this

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'm learning how JavaScript implements OOP and working through different object-creation patterns. Currently, I'm working on a small problem to get a better feel for the "Pseudo-classical Pattern". I've defined a constructor function `Person` which initializes some properties when it's called. Rather than defining the methods on the constructor, I want to define the methods on the prototype `Person.prototype`.

The calls to the other methods defined on `Person.prototype` output the expected values, but the call to `Person.prototype.fullName` isn't working as expected. The method should return a string concatenating the `firstName` and `lastName` properties defined on the calling object, but the method instead returns `undefined undefined`. When I call `this` from `fullName`, an empty object is returned rather than the `person` instance as I expected.

I'm not clear on why `this` in the instance method `fullName` isn't referencing the calling object. It's my understanding that calling the method on the `person` instance, the instance should delegate the call to the prototype. In the prototype, `this` should still reference the calling object, in which case `this.firstName` should return `Tony`, and `this.lastName` should return `Takitani`. Instead, both references are returning `undefined`, since the properties are undefined on `{}`.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
let Person = function(firstName, lastName, age, gender) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
};

Person.prototype.fullName = () => {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; 
  // this returns {}
};

Person.prototype.communicate = () => {
  console.log(`I'm communicating`);
};

Person.prototype.eat = () => {
  console.log("I'm eating");
};

Person.prototype.sleep = () => {
  console.log('ZzzZzzZzzzz');
};


const person = new Person('Tony', 'Takitani', 21, 'male');
console.log(person instanceof Person);     // logs true
person.eat();                              // logs 'I'm eating'
person.communicate();                      // logs 'I'm communicating'
person.sleep();                            // logs 'ZzzZzzZzzzz'


console.log(person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName ) // Tony Takitani

console.log(person.fullName());
```

Comment: `=>` functions are not the same as `function` functions, and in particular they don't set the value of `this`.

Comment: Related: [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379) | [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982)