# How to pass variables initialized in beforeEach to reusable test function outside closure

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Lets imagine rather simple jasmine unit test setup

```js
  let actions$: Subject<Action>;
  let effects: CustomEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions$ = new Subject<Action>();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CustomEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(CustomEffects);
  });

  
    testLoadingIndicators(
      simpleParamsPassedWithoutProblem,
      { effects, actions$ }, // <-- undefined, undefined
    );
```

I want to create reusable testing function (defined in other file) that will take some params and effects and actions$ variables. The problem is those last two are initialized in beforeEach so by the time they are passed to my testing fn they are not yet ready.

My end goal here is to have the testing function I can reuse across many files in my test setup. This testing function has `describes` and `its` and uses provided params to do the logic.

The usual way of writing such tests uses closure to access the variable, but this would mean declaring my test fn inside outer describe and thus making it not shareable.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use scope to share data. `beforeEach()` and `beforeAll()` are [already equipped to set up shareable data between all tests by using `this`](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite#section-The_%3Ccode%3Ethis%3C/code%3E_keyword): any properties defined in a setup function will be visible in `it()` callbacks. The same cannot be done in `describe()`, however `beforeEach()` can be called in a `describe()` callback and will be scoped to only that one callback:

```js
beforeAll(function() {
  this.foo = 1;
});

beforeEach(function() {
  this.bar = 2;
});

describe('beforeAll', function() {
  it('this.foo is 1', function() {
    expect(this.foo).toEqual(1);
  });
});

describe('beforeEach', function() {
  it('this.bar is 2', function() {
    expect(this.bar).toEqual(2);
  });
});

describe('`this` is passed down to `it()` calls not to describe()', function() {
  this.bar = 3;
  this.baz = "whatever";
  
  it('this.foo is inherited', function() {
    expect(this.foo).toEqual(1);
  });
  
  it('this.bar is NOT overridden in describe()', function() {
    expect(this.bar).toEqual(2);
  });
  
  it('this.baz has not been added in describe()', function() {
    expect(this.baz).toBeUndefined();
  });
  
  const thisInDescribe = this;
  it('describe() does not have access to the `this` in `beforeEach()`/`beforeAll()', function() {
    expect(this).not.toEqual(thisInDescribe);
  });
});

describe('can use beforeEach() in describe ', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.bar = 3;
    this.baz = 4;
  });
  
  it('this.foo is inherited', function() {
    expect(this.foo).toEqual(1);
  });
  
  it('this.bar is overridden in describe()', function() {
    expect(this.bar).toEqual(3);
  });
  
  it('this.baz has not been added in describe()', function() {
    expect(this.baz).toEqual(4);
  });
});

describe('beforeEach() used in a describe() does not leak to other describe()s ', function() {
  it('this.bar is still the same as the global beforeEach()', function() {
    expect(this.bar).toEqual(2);
  });
  
  it('this.baz does not exist', function() {
    expect(this.baz).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot1.min.js"></script>
```

**Important note 1:** you have to use regular functions and **not arrow functions**, to be able to properly use `this` since arrow functions have `this` set at creation time. For more information see

- [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379))
- [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371982)
- [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

**Important note 2:** The `beforeAll()` setup should be used sparsely as it can contaminate the context of tests. It is better to use `beforeEach()` which will guaranteed re-set the context between tests. If needed the teardown functions[`afterAll()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.1/global.html#afterAll)/[`afterEach()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.1/global.html#afterEach) can be used to clean up after tests. But this is rarely needed.

---

With this mechanism in place, you can extract `describe()` and/or `it()`:

```js
//this can be in another file
function parametarisedDescribe(whatToAdd, whatToExpect) {
  describe('this is some test', function() {
    it('adding is correct', function() {
      const actual = this.bar + whatToAdd;
      
      expect(actual).toEqual(whatToExpect);
    });
  });
}

function parametariseIt(whatToRepeat, whatToExpect) {
  it('repeating is correct', function() {
    const actual = whatToRepeat.repeat(this.bar);

    expect(actual).toEqual(whatToExpect);
  });
}


//only in test file
beforeEach(function() {
  this.bar = 2;
});

parametarisedDescribe(40, 42); // 2 + 40 = 42  - pass
parametarisedDescribe(40, 41); // 2 + 40 != 41 - fail

describe("static describe() with parametarised it()s", function() {
  parametariseIt("a", "aa"); // "a".repeat(2)  = "aa" - pass
  parametariseIt("b", "BB"); // "b".repeat(2) != "BB" - fail
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot1.min.js"></script>
```

Note that it is also possible to extract only the callback given to `describe()`/`it()` and use those. For example:

```js
//define describe()/it() callback separately
function myDescribe() {
  it('adding is correct', function() {
    const actual = 2 + this.whatToAdd;

    expect(actual).toEqual(this.whatToExpect);
  });
}

function myIt() {
  const actual = this.whatToRepeat.repeat(2);

  expect(actual).toEqual(this.whatToExpect);
}


//use the callbacks
//NOTE: these are all in here for convenience 
// any group of these tests can also be in a separate spec file
describe("adding test passes", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.whatToAdd    = 40;
    this.whatToExpect = 42;
  });
  
  describe('2 + 40 == 42', myDescribe);
});

describe("addint test fails", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.whatToAdd    = 40;
    this.whatToExpect = 41;
  });
  
  describe('2 + 40 != 41', myDescribe);
});

describe('repeating "a" ', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.whatToRepeat = "a";
    this.whatToExpect = "aa";
  });
  it('"a".repeat(2) == "aa"', myIt);
});

  
describe('repeating "b"', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.whatToRepeat = "b";
    this.whatToExpect = "BB";
  });
  it('"b".repeat(2) != "BB"', myIt);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/5.0.1/boot1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok so to sum up - you are proposing the use of `this`. I have two issues with it: one - it is a clear deviation from the common practice of Angular unit tests, and two - we got about 4k units and migrating all that to regular function is quite a huge refactor. https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#cli-generated-tests

Comment: @Mike I'm giving you the correct tool for the job. What you're saying is that so far you've hammered all the screws and thus a screwdriver would mean a lot of changes. If you want to keep hammering away, you can define a function that takes parameters then in the place where you have a `beforeEach` add an `it()` which passes forward the parameters `it("is a test", () => myTestFn(param1, param2))` which is boilerplate but at least less code.

Comment: Still hammer-y is to create one global variable and in the `beforeEach` assign properties. It's like using `this` but worse. At least allows you to pass that global object around and do something like what you do here, but in `testLoadingIndicators` you can define your `it()` tests and inside the callbacks you can use `myGlobalAsParam.effects` which should be populated. Take your pick if you prefer bad-but-slightly-convenient solution.